# Getting variables within the __init__ def in python in some class

Tags: python, function

I have a class with certain inside variables in it, let's take a simple example

```
    class Example:
        def __init__(self):
            self.variable = "something"
            self.anotherVariable = "somethingElse"
```

Now the signature in "inspect" only provides me with what's in the brackets, which in this case only the self, but can I somehow get a list of variable names within the class, so if I run that code it will result in:

> Output:
>   (self.variable, self.anotherVariable)

I appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need `inspect`:

```
class Example:
        def __init__(self):
            self.variable = "something"
            self.anotherVariable = "somethingElse"
print(Example.__init__.__code__.co_names)
```

Output:

```
('variable', 'anotherVariable')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is like this; invoking dir on object itself:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = 1
        self.anotherVariable = 2

obj = Example()
print([attrib for attrib in dir(obj) if not attrib.startswith("_")])
```

O/P

```
['variable', 'anotherVariable']
```

Comment: This solution is pretty smart too, I like it, but due to the fact is takes a place with a for loop and I assume the others doesn't, I also assume its overall speed is slightly slower, I don't really understand much when it comes to hardware speed and how coding affects it but pretty sure it has something to do with loops... lol, let's not get into this subject. But it looks like an amazing solution to this problem so thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I used list comprehensions to print only user defined attributes. If you just print `dir(obj)` it will give all the inbuilt methods and attributes on that object.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this I prefer `__dict__`.

This is built into every class you make unless you override it. Since we’re dealing with a Python dictionary, we can just call its keys method.

Here is an example.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "something"
        self.anotherVariable = "somethingElse"

obj = Example()

variables = obj.__dict__.keys()
```

Output --> `['varTwo', 'varThree', 'varOne']`

Hope this helps. There are also few other methods you can check out here :

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/01/11/how-to-get-a-list-of-class-attributes/

Comment: This solution works just as well! Thanks too! May I ask though, can I use the outputs I got the set the variables, like.. if I got this list can I set every variable accordingly from the outside?

Comment: Yes definitely. You can use `setattr(obj, variable[0], "something2")` to set the value of the keys you got in response.